# Slack Slash Command - Passing custom POST paramater?

Tags: wordpress, slack-api, slack

Is it possible to send `POST` data along with a Slash Command?

For example, when setting up a new Slash Command I can set the callback URL that will receive the `POST` data from Slack. In my case it's

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php
```

I am writing this as a Wordpress plugin, and in order to have the plugin parse the `POST` data I need to pass along an `action` variable in the `POST` data.

```
action=update_status
```

... so that the correct action is called:

```
add_action('admin_update_status', function() {
    // Parse POST
});
```

Is it possible to send a custom `POST` parameter with the slash command? Maybe something like:

```
/update action:update_status ProjectA is currently in Q/A
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out I can also send the `action` parameter as a `GET` request like so:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=update_status
```